# Delicious Bundle Tags Log in from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delicious-api

I would like to know if there is a way to specify the user credetianls when calling the Delicious API to get all the Bundle Tags. I am using the following url from C#.

```
string DelAPI = "https://api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/bundles/all?";
```

However, when I call the url it ask me for the credentials. If I put the same url in any browser it would be the same. There, after I write my user nd password I am able to se all the bundle tags I have. But, how could I achieved the same from C# code?

An clue, comment, code would be very usefull.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this approach: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/152297-c%23-log-in-to-website-programmatically/ could be helpful